# ¿Por que el map no muestra la información?

Tags: reactjs, map

No sé en que estoy fallando y la verdad que no tengo a nadie que sepa y le pueda consultar, me tira el sigueinte error :

> Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): casos.map is not a function.

La data la traigo bien , pero me falta algo que hace que no pueda utilizarla no se que es:

```
    import axios from "axios";
    import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
    
    export const PaisesAxios = () => {
      const [casos, setCasos] = useState([]);
      useEffect(() => {
        axios.get("https://covid-api.mmediagroup.fr/v1/cases").then((res) => {
          console.log(res.data.Global);
          setCasos(res.data.Global);
        });
      }, []);
    
      return (
        <div>
          {casos.map((e) => (
            <div key={e.confirmed}>
              <p>casos confirmados:{e.confirmed}</p>
            </div>
          ))}
        </div>
      );
    };
```

Comment: Muchisimas gracias por la explicación ,  me van a ver mas seguido apartir de ahora jaja

Comment: Que bueno que lograste avanzar, no olvides [aceptar la respuesta y dar tu voto](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers), esto ayuda a mantener el sitio bien documentado. Saludos

Answer (score 1):

La variable de estado `casos` se inicializa como un `Array`:

```
const [casos, setCasos] = useState([]);
```

Luego la propiedad `res.data.Global` es un `Objeto JS`, no un `Array`:

```
console.log(res.data.Global);//esto es un objeto js
```

Después, al aplicar `setCasos`, se cambia el valor de `casos` de `array` a `objeto`; por eso cuando se trata de procesar `casos` en el `return` con `map` se obtiene:

> Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): casos.map is not a function.

`map` es un método del tipo `Array JS`, no de `Object JS`

---

Se puede acceder a la propiedad `All` y aplicar el `set` al estado `casos` como un objeto, aquí el demo:

```js
function App() {
  const [casos, setCasos] = React.useState({});
  React.useEffect(() => {
    axios.get("https://covid-api.mmediagroup.fr/v1/cases").then((res) => {
      console.log(res.data);
      setCasos(res.data.Global.All);
    });
  }, []);

  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <div>
        <p>Casos confirmados:{casos.confirmed}</p>
      </div>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById('root'))
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/axios/dist/axios.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@17/umd/react.development.js" crossorigin ></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@17/umd/react-dom.development.js" crossorigin ></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

#### Notas de campo

- Se puede usar `Object.values` para transformar una estructura tipo `Objeto JS` a un `Array JS`.

[Doc Object.values](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values)

Answer (score 0):

Esto podría servirte, armé este componente completo para probarlo:

```
import axios from "axios";
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import "./App.css";

function App() {
  const [casos, setCasos] = useState({});
  useEffect(() => {
    axios.get("https://covid-api.mmediagroup.fr/v1/cases").then((res) => {
      console.log(res.data);
      setCasos(res.data.Global.All);
    });
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div>
        <p>casos confirmados:{casos.confirmed}</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

No te funciona primero porque estás poniendo como valor inicial del useState un array, y no hay ningún array, todos los resultados son objetos.

**res.data** devulve un objeto llamado **Global**

**Global** tiene adentro un objeto llamado **All**

Y finalmente dentro del objeto **All** tenemos una **key** que se llama **confirmed**

Por último como no tenemos ningún array no es aplicable el map, ya que depositamos en el state ahora un objeto, podemos acceder al valor deseado por medio de {casos.confirmed}

Espero sirva para resolver tu inconveniente.

Quedo a las ordenes.

Comment: Muchisimas gracias